# get-service shows my service but not services.msc, how do I get it in services.msc?

Tags: windows, winapi, service, windows-services

I used Go to create a new service, specifically [`Mgr.CreateService`](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/sys/windows/svc/mgr#Mgr.CreateService) ([code](https://github.com/golang/sys/blob/b5fbb47/windows/svc/mgr/mgr.go#L109-L159) ; which calls [`CreateServiceW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsvc/nf-winsvc-createservicew)), but it doesn't appear in services.msc.

It appears in PowerShell's [`get-service`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-service?view=powershell-7.3), and [`net start`](https://ss64.com/nt/net-service.html) works.

How do I get it to appear in services.msc?

EDIT: Comparing two entries in Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Service:

```
- Mine:   "Start"=dword:00000003
- Theirs: "Start"=dword:00000002
- Mine:   "ErrorControl"=dword:00000000
- Theirs: "ErrorControl"=dword:00000001
- Mine:   <missing value>
- Theirs: "DependOnService"=hex(7):52,00,50,00,43,00,53,00,53,00,00,00,00,00
- Mine:   "ObjectName"="LocalSystem"
- Theirs: "ObjectName"="NT AUTHORITY\\NetworkService"
```

So what I *think* is going on is that it needs to have an ObjectName matching the above? - Is that related to the DependOnService [their value: RPCSS; which I believe is the Remote Procedure Call Windows Service]?

EDIT1:

```golang
//go:build windows

package mypackage

import (
    "fmt"
    "path/filepath"

    "golang.org/x/sys/windows/svc/eventlog"
    "golang.org/x/sys/windows/svc/mgr"
)

func windowsServiceInstall(name, binary, cliArgs string) error {
    var err error
    var m *mgr.Mgr
    if m, err = mgr.Connect(); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer func(m *mgr.Mgr) {
        if err = m.Disconnect(); err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    }(m)

    var service *mgr.Service
    if service, err = m.OpenService(name); err == nil {
        if err = service.Close(); err != nil {
            return err
        }
        return fmt.Errorf("service %s already exists", name)
    }
    if service, err = m.CreateService(
        name,
        binary,
        mgr.Config{DisplayName: name,
            BinaryPathName: fmt.Sprintf("%s %s", binary, cliArgs),
        },
        "is", "auto-started",
    ); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer func(service *mgr.Service) {
        if e := service.Close(); e != nil {
            panic(e)
        }
    }(service)
    if err = eventlog.InstallAsEventCreate(name, eventlog.Error|eventlog.Warning|eventlog.Info); err != nil {
        if e := service.Delete(); e != nil {
            return e
        }
        return fmt.Errorf("SetupEventLogSource() failed: %s", err)
    }

    return nil
}
```

Comment: I would help if you showed your code here. At the risk of potentially saying something obvious that you have already tried - are you sure that it is not in services.msc? Remember that services.msc does not show the service name in the list, but the Display Name so if different your service may be elsewhere in the list.

Comment: DependOnService is only relevant if your service depends on another service

Comment: ObjectName is the name of the account the service run under

Comment: Sure thing, see my edit for Go code

Answer (score 0):

There may be a missing service dependency or the call to create the service is not configured correctly.
If your service depends on other services to function correctly, you must specify those dependencies when you create the service. You can do this by using the SetDependencies method of the mgr.Service object. For example:

```
dependencies := []string{"RPCSS"} // Add here the necessary dependencies for your service
if err = service.SetDependencies(dependencies); err != nil {
    return err
}
```

You could try to configure your service as the existing one to see if it appears:

```
if service, err = m.CreateService(
    name,
    binary,
    mgr.Config{
        DisplayName:    name,
        BinaryPathName: fmt.Sprintf("%s %s", binary, cliArgs),
        StartType:      mgr.StartAutomatic,
        ErrorControl:   windows.SERVICE_ERROR_NORMAL,
        ServiceStartName: "NT AUTHORITY\\NetworkService", // Set the ServiceStartName to NT AUTHORITY\\NetworkService
    },
    "is", "auto-started",
); err != nil {
    return err
}
```